# Simple .NET file system persistence?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, persistence

I need to store some simple data (just some POCO objects with a few attributes, nothing fancy).

```
public class MyPOCO
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    // ...
}
```

Basically, at some point of my web application I need to check if the `MyPOCO` object is already persisted (matching by `Id`), and if it's not, persist it. That's all I need.

It can't be any database, so probably `XML` or `JSON`. What's an easy way (or Nuget package) to store it?

Comment: Why can't it be a database?

Comment: @DanielBrückner That's all the persistence the application needs. It needs to be easily deployable to any IIS without any sql server instance.

Comment: Why not use Session Variables? for example when the application starts
`protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)` set session variables / initialize them there `HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] = 0;` etc...

Comment: How many objects? You can use XML but you are going to need to deal with locks while it writes.  You don't ever read from this?  Why would you not just read the IDs into a HashSet when the application starts?

Comment: @Blam No, no reading. It's kind of a log, a "`DISTINCT LOG`" if you want. Anyway, I guess I'll go for SQL Server CE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a in-process database like [SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) together with an O/R mapper. This is easier and more maintainable than reinventing a small database.

Comment: I guess I'll go with this approach. Any good micro ORM that plays well and easy with SQL Server CE?

Comment: I would just use Entity Framework with code first. It is probably not the most light weight alternative but it just works and given that it is not at the core of your application overhead should not be a concern.